# Sortable JQuery UI Issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery draggable and droppable with sortable operations,im able to drag and drop from one div section to another  but in droppable div section im facing issue while performing sorting operation.

while i drag contents from draggable div section to droppable div section it must dynamically take list decimal and i should able to sort(move forth and back) in droppable div section.

please help me out in implementing Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/j6dqk54p/4/

**html code**

```
<div>
        <ol id="sortable"></ol>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <ul id="draggable">
            <li>
                <div class="qitem">
                    <div>
                        <span class="question">Item1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="qitem">
                    <div>
                        <span class="question">Item2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert: true,
                refreshPositions: true ,
                helper : 'clone',
                cursor: "move",
                delay: 1,
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                revert: 50
        });

        $("#sortable").disableSelection();

        $(".qitem").draggable({
            //containment : "#container",
            tolerance:"pointer",
            helper : 'clone',
            refreshPositions: true ,
            revert : 'invalid',
            opacity:.4,
        });

        $("#sortable").droppable({
            revert:true,
            hoverClass : 'ui-state-highlight',
            greedy: true,
            refreshPositions: true,
            drop : function(ev, ui) 
            {
                $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
                if($(this)[0].id === "sortable")
                {
                    console.log($(this).closest("button").find('.hello'));
                    $(this).find('.hello').hide();
                    $(this).find('.btn').show();
                    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' ).closest('li').prependTo(ui.draggable.closest('ul'));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```